# Drawing multiple lines of triangles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to draw 3 lines of triangles to an HTML canvas with vanilla JS.
I divided my canvas into `1/8*cw` *(canvas widht)* wide columns and `1/8*ch` *(canvas hight)* high rows. I know that `2/8` is the same as `1/4`, but until I'm finished with my code, I want to leave it like this. This is why I've calculated with the numbers as seen. I've broken up the picture into three rows of triangles, with an increasing number of triangles in each row. For this reason, I chose nested loops to solve the whole thing. But for some reason, it is not working, the last triangle is not there.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;
var k = 1;
var x = 5 / 8 * cw;
var y = -1 / 8 * ch;

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x -= 1 / 8 * cw, y += 2 / 8 * ch);
  for (var j = 0; j < k; j++) {
    context.moveTo(x += j * (2 / 8 * cw), y);
    context.lineTo(x - 1 / 8 * cw, y + 2 / 8 * ch);
    context.lineTo(x + 1 / 8 * cw, y + 2 / 8 * ch);
    context.closePath();
    if (y === 1 / 8 * ch) {
      context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 77, 77)';
    } else if (y === 3 / 8 * ch) {
      context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 179, 60)';
    } else {
      context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 153, 153)';
    }
    context.fill();
    console.log('i: ' + i + ' j: ' + j + ' k: ' + k);
  }
  k += 1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="300" width="450" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I want 3 triangles on the last (third) line.

Comment: This might help: https://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/a79txb2z/. I've not changed much, just added some debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is very difficult to read and hard to debug. Putting equations that change values like x += ... in parameters is bad practice and you should avoid it at all cost. This is a major cause of failure in your code.

Here is your fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/9oqmx3cL/ you will have to compare what changed.

I know you didn't ask for a code review, still, you probably best reading through this rewritten code below and pick up some tips. Granted, it only plot in a single color. If you pass color as a parameter to the triangle function based on the row variable being 0, then 1, then 2, then that task is very simple to add without some having complex formula like if (y === 3 / 8 * ch) {...} to do the same thing. When you start adding 4th, 5th row, the formula logic becomes more messy.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;


var maxRows = 3;

var width  = 1 / 8 * ch;
var height = 1 / 8 * ch;

var yPos = 0;

var halfTriangleWidth = width / 2;
var middleOfCanvasX   = cw / 2;

for (var row = 0; row < maxRows; row++) {
    var xPos = middleOfCanvasX - (row * halfTriangleWidth);
    for (var col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
       plotTriangle(context, xPos, yPos, width, height);
       xPos += width;
    }
    yPos += height;
}

function plotTriangle(context, x, y, w, h) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 153, 153)';

  context.moveTo(x, y);
  context.lineTo(x + w / 2, y + h);
  context.lineTo(x - w / 2, y + h);
  context.closePath();  
  context.fill();
}
```